# Installing MS Office on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: wine, microsoft-office

I've installed wine with:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

I've downloaded OfficeSetup.exe from the official Microsoft website (student license) and then I typed in the terminal:

> sudo su
>
> ...
>
> wine "OfficeSetup.exe"

I see the Office logo with the loading animation, and after a few seconds it appears to me an error message saying that the installation can't proceed with these possible motivations:

1. internet connection down,
2. no space available on disk,

but any of these are true in my situation.
No other replies in the terminal, no other warnings from wine, anything.

What could I do?

Comment: Speaking from experience, the Office software runs faster, better, and with fewer resources when done from inside a browser. I use Edge for all the O365 stuff my employer insists on using and it’s been responsive and consistent … though Teams will hit a race condition and take your CPU to 100% on occasion. If you can use the online versions of the applications, you might find that you prefer it to something that is emulated and consuming more storage space than it’s worth.

Comment: First of all never use `sudo` with `wine`.

Comment: Install `playonlinux` it makes MS Office installation much easier.

Comment: PlayOnLinux will be your best bet. You won't be successful 100% but just with a bit of trial and error you'd be able to do. PlayOnLinux allows you to easily install different versions of Wine. Your luck depends on this.